# How to search certain files from certain subdirectories using python

Tags: python-3.x, operating-system

I have directories like this:

```
MOL1 MOL2 MOL3 dir1 test1 scripts
```

This code is in `scripts` directory and what I want to do is loop through all directories that start with `MOL` and search for files that start with `info`

```
import os

def get_info():
    parent = os.pardir
    contents = os.listdir(parent)
    list1 = []

    for dir in contents:
        if dir.startswith("MOL"):
            for file in dir:
                path = os.path.join(parent, file)
                if file.startswith("info"):
                    with open(path, "r") as data:
                        text = data.readlines()
                        for num1, row1 in enumerate(text):
                            row1 = row1.rstrip("\n").split()
                            list1.append(row1)
    list2 = []
    #do stuff for list2
    return list2

get_info()
```

But this does not work. Nothing happens when I run this. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted depends on the location of your work directory, i.e. the directory from where you call your script, which is not necessarily the parent folder of the script. You can use the built-in `__file__` property to find paths relative to your script:

```py
from pathlib import Path

script_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
info_files = script_dir.parent.glob('MOL*/info*')
for info_file in info_files:
    # do something with the file
```

Have a look at the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module which provides a more convenient interface to the file system.

Answer (score -1):

The practical way of debugging this is just using `print` statements as it finds the directory and files.